# Can't Access VMware VM Remotely

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, virtualbox, vmware-player

I have a VM several layers away that I want to access remotely, but I can't get to it for some reason.  I've tried several things to figure it out, and I wonder if I am missing something.  I would like to RDP into the machine or access the web application running on port 80 on the VM.

Here's the setup...

- VM in question:  VMWare VM, Windows Server 2003, PeopleSoft
- VMWare Host: Virtualbox VM, Xubuntu 15.04 basic installation
- Physical Server: IBM x3455, Ubuntu Server 15.04
- Laptop: Ubuntu Desktop 15.04

The reason for the complicated setup is that it is temporary.  I want to be able to make some changes to the "VM in question" and then give it back to the person who gave it to me.  I don't want to clutter up my "Physical Server" with VMware when I don't plan to use it on an on-going basis.

*Basically, I want to connect to the "VM in question" from the "Laptop".*

Here's what I have tried:

**Network set to Bridged**

"VMware Host" has a network adapter set to bind.  I went to Machine Settings > Network > Adapter 1 and set the "Attached to" option to "Bridged Adapter".

"VM in question" also has the network adapter set to bind.  I went to Virtual Machine > Virtual Machine Settings > Network Adapter and selected the Bridged radio button.

So, my machines are all on the same subnet/network.  Here are the IP addresses:

- VM in question: 192.168.x.103
- VMWare Host: 192.168.x.105
- Physical Server: 192.168.x.15
- Laptop: 192.168.x.110

**DNS**

I don't think that DNS is a problem.  On my laptop, when I try to ping the VM in question it gets the IP address correct:

```
$ ping VM
PING VM (192.168.x.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- VM ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2014ms
```

**Ping**

I tried pinging at the different levels to see where the network traffic was getting stopped.

- On the "VM in question", I can ping it's own IP address.
- On the "VMware Host", I can ping the "VM in question"
- On the "Physical Server", I **cannot** ping the "VM in question"

**Firewall**

I think the Xubuntu firewall was turned on in the "VMware Host".  I have that off now.

I checked with:

```
user@VMWareHost:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for user: 
Status: inactive
```

I originally turned it off with:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

**Question**

Do you see anything I missed?  Is there a way to get network access to that VM from my laptop?

Comment: Have you allowed access through the network firewall that this VM is behind?

Comment: I don't think there is a firewall that I know of involved.  The "VMWare Host" is a VM sitting on the "Physical Server".  I can't ping between from the server to the either VMs.  Maybe it is a Xubuntu thing?  Maybe the firewall in Xubuntu isn't really turned off even though it says it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem with the Network Adapter, I solved it by go to **Edit** option in VMWare, **Virtual Network Editor** and **Restore Defaults**.